# ReactJS : cannot read properoties of undefined (reading 'then') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, rest, undefined

Here is my code (I was following a youtube video for calling REST API). It is giving problem at **"then((response..."** below

**src/components/EmployeeComponent.js
**

```
import React from "react";
import EmployeeService from "../services/EmployeeService";

class EmployeeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((response) => {
            this.setState({ employees: response.data });
        });

        //EmployeeService.getEmployees = () => {
        //  axios.get("employees").then((response) => {this.setState ( {emmployees: response.data,});
        //  } );
        //};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-center"> Employee List</h1>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Employee First Name</td>
                            <td> Employee Last Name</td>
                            <td> Manager ID</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.employees.map((employee) => (
                            <tr key={employee.first_name}>
                                <td> {employee.first_name}</td>
                                <td>{employee.last_name}</td>
                                <td>{employee.manager_id}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EmployeeComponent;
```

*Now I have EmployeeService.js in src/services/EmployeeComponent.js . here also it is complaining when I am trying to export *

```
import axios from "axios";

const EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

class EmployeeService {
    getEmployees() {
        axios.get(EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL);
    }
}

export default new EmployeeService();
```

I am getting following error

Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
at EmployeeComponent.componentDidMount (http://localhost:3000/main.9a0e6d67a8efe7f76fca.hot-update.js:33:85)
at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29607:34)
at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30774:13)
at commitLayoutEffects_begin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30763:11)
at commitLayoutEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30709:7)
at commitRootImpl

I am not very knowledgeable in reactJS and am starting after a long time

I have tried :

```
import axios from "axios";

const EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

class EmployeeService {
    getEmployees() {
        axios.get(EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL);
    }
}

//export default new EmployeeService();

const employeeServiceObject = new EmployeeService();

export default employeeServiceObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getEmployees() function is not returning anything .There are 2 ways of doing it

**1.Simple Function**

```
 getEmployees() {
     return   axios.get(EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL);
    }
```

**2.Arrow Function**

```
 getEmployees=()=>axios.get(EMPLOYEES_REST_API_URL);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Muhammad, but now I am getting a different error:

EmployeeComponent.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.employees.map is not a function
    at EmployeeComponent.render (EmployeeComponent.js:40:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:42

Comment: <tbody>
      {
       this.state.employees.map (
        employee =>
        <tr key = {employee.first_name}>
         <td> {employee.first_name}</td>
         <td>{employee.last_name}</td>
         <td>{employee.manager_id}</td>
        </tr>
       )
      }
     </tbody>


It is also shown in the original code

Comment: @AC what is the response in component did mount .console.log it and tell me the response so i can help.

Comment: So, I put this :

componentDidMount() {
  EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((response) => {
   console.log("First time " + response.data);
   this.setState({employees: response.data});
   console.log("Second time " + response.data);
  });

Surprisingly it is printing "First time" and "Second time" twice and in between the two times it has an error also. But it doesn't print anything else which tells me that there is no response coming back??

Comment: Muhammad, thank you so much. Based on your suggestion and help, I was able to figure out myself. Actually I wasn't returning anything from the REST controller and that's why it was empty. So, now it is working. Thank you...